# What can be the least score in elastic search?

Tags: elasticsearch

The `_search` API in the elastic search provides the results document with positive scores. What can be the least score in a set of documents other than zero?

This can be helpful to use the `min_score` parameter to avoid the documents without non-zero score results.

Comment: Score must be positive, so min is 0.

Answer (score 2):

## Tldr;

Score in elasticsearch has to be a positive 32-bit floating point.
[As per the documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#function-script-score)

> In Elasticsearch, all document scores are positive 32-bit floating point numbers.
>
> If the script_score function produces a score with greater precision, it is converted to the nearest 32-bit float.
>
> Similarly, scores must be non-negative. Otherwise, Elasticsearch returns an e

So it can go quite low

| Floating Point | Largest value | Smallest value1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 32-bit Float | 3.4028237 × 1038 | 1.175494 × 10-38 |